# Unity Cursor only returning one position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my cursor to return a vector 3 for it's screen position (using the new Input system) but it only returns one position on the screen rather than whatever position the cursor is at
this is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class FollowCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 worldPosition;
    public GameObject cursorObject;
    public GameObject cursor;
    public Transform FirePoint;
    [SerializeField] Camera maincamera;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = maincamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
        mousePos.z = 10;
        Debug.Log(mousePos);
        cursorObject.transform.localPosition = mousePos;
        cursor.transform.position = cursorObject.transform.position;

        Physics.Linecast(FirePoint.position, cursorObject.transform.position);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(FirePoint.position, cursorObject.transform.position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably do this in the Update function instead of FixedUpdate.

I have not used Mouse.current.position.ReadValue() before. HAve you tried using Input.mousePosition instead? This usually works for me.

Comment: yes I have tried using Input.mousePosition before, I switched to the new input system since it didn't work either